# Changing the value being passed through the parameter

Tags: java, parameters, reference, parameter-passing

I was testing whether you can change the value of the static variable x by passing it through a parameter, but I found out that you can't do it like that.

```
public class Test {
static int x;

static void changeX(int x_) {
    x_ = 50;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    changeX(x);
    System.out.println(x);//it prints out zero because the static variable did not get changed


}

}
```

If we do it like this, we can change it:

```
public class Test {
static int x;

static void changeX(int x_) {
    x = 50;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    changeX(x);
    System.out.println(x);

}

}
```

Which means you have to directly reference to the static variable in order to change it. Okay. Now. My question is, is there a way to change a class variable by just passing it through the parameter, without referencing it in the implementation? Basically, is there a way to use the first way somehow? Thanks.

Comment: No, at least not with primitive type or wrapper `Integer` type.

Comment: Java is _always_ pass by value. You can't change passed-in primitive parameter values through a function call.

Comment: I thought if you change the value in the parameter, the value being passed through the parameter gets changed too. x.x There's really no way to do that? It would be really useful if it could somehow be done.

Comment: You can do it using reflection

Comment: @nmelssx It's never possible with _primitive_ types, to change the external value with a function call. You can update object references through a function call, but that's only true for non immutable types as well. You have the ability to update object references through a function call by using the reference directly (because it points to the same memory location), but you can't reassign the parameter to another object reference and have the original be updated, since the _reference_ is passed by value.

Comment: @RyanJ when it is a wrapper Integer object the value of static is still not changing. Here is another flavor. public class Test {
    static int x=0;
    static void changeX(int x_) {
        x_= 50;
        x=x_;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        changeX(x);
        System.out.println(x);//it prints out zero because the static variable did not get changed
    }
}

Comment: @SathishJayapal I said _non immutable types_, and you didn't actually use an Integer object in that example.

Comment: @RyanJ correct., I did not, but even when I used a wrapper Integer it was giving the same result. public class Test {
    static Integer x=0;
    static void changeX(Integer x_) {
        x_= 50;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        changeX(x);
        System.out.println(x);//it prints out zero because the static variable did not get changed
    }
}I might be missing something., Cheers.

Comment: @SathishJayapal _"you can't reassign the parameter to another object reference and have the original be updated, since the reference is passed by value"_ You're not trying to update via the object reference, you're trying to _change_ the reference, which is not going to work. Also, your first example is bogus, it works just fine, because you're directly modifying the static variable using the parameter value. Just like a "setter".

Comment: @RyanJ this is really weird, but when I pass a Jframe in as a parameter, and just update the jframe in the parameter without making a reference to the actual jframe I'm using, it actually updates it! Basically I made the method to show the jframe being passed through the method on the screen, and it works! for some reason! I'm so confucious now.

Comment: @nmelssx See my comment on the answer below. You can update object references by accessing and modifying their public members (or through a public interface), but what you can't do is re-assign the parameter to another object to update the original object. The _reference_ itself, is a copy. The object it points to, is not.

Comment: So basically we can't do it, right?

Comment: @nmelssx no, that's not what I'm saying. You _can_, it's just you need to be aware of the type you're trying to change, and use the proper mechanisms to do so. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* achieve what you are asking, but you need to be aware of the subtle limitations. You can modify an object reference passed into a method, but you cannot *reassign* the reference in the method and have the original object be changed.

Java is *always* pass by value. Period.
Object references, are passed by value, but it is through those references (which point to the same memory location), that you can modify objects inside of methods, through the parameter.

You *cannot* modify primitives (`int`, `float`, `boolean`, etc) in this manner, they are always passed by value. You also cannot modify immutable objects (such as `String`), as they cannot be changed using a public interface.

Consider this simple example, which tests creating an object with some modifiable fields, by-value, and by-reference (it's modifying by object reference, that itself is passed by value):

```
public class ParameterPassingTest {
    static SomeObject someStaticObject;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize a static object reference
        someStaticObject = new SomeObject("I am a static Object", 10);

        System.out.println("My static object before: " + someStaticObject);

        // try modifying the reference by value
        modifySomeObjectByValue(someStaticObject);
        // try printing the value, it will be the same
        System.out.println("My static object after mod-by-value: " + someStaticObject);

        // now, try modifying by object reference
        modifySomeObjectByReference(someStaticObject);

        // print again. new values should be observed
        System.out.println("My static object after mod-by-reference: " + someStaticObject);
    }

    // this method tries to modify the original object by assigning directly to the method parameter. It won't work.
    public static void modifySomeObjectByValue(SomeObject someObject) {
        SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject("I am another object, from a local method", 20);
        someObject = newObject; // try to modify the original object by assigning to the parameter directly
    }

    // this method tries to modify the original object by using the object's public interface. It works.
    public static void modifySomeObjectByReference(SomeObject someObject) {
        // try to modify the original object by using the reference passed in
        someObject.setaString("I have been modified by a method");
        someObject.setAnInt(50);
    }
}

// simple, generic class object with some fields.
class SomeObject {
    String aString;
    int anInt;

    public SomeObject(String aString, int anInt) {
        this.aString = aString;
        this.anInt = anInt;
    }

    public String getaString() {
        return aString;
    }

    public void setaString(String aString) {
        this.aString = aString;
    }

    public int getAnInt() {
        return anInt;
    }

    public void setAnInt(int anInt) {
        this.anInt = anInt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "aString = " + getaString() + " | anInt = " + getAnInt();
    }
}
```

This produces output:

```
My static object before: aString = I am a static Object | anInt = 10
My static object after mod-by-value: aString = I am a static Object | anInt = 10
My static object after mod-by-reference: aString = I have been modified by a method | anInt = 50
```

Answer (score -2):

Java passes primitives always as value. Objects on the other hand are always passed as reference. In your second example, you access the static attribute `x` and not the parameter `x_`.
Furthermore, `static` does not protect an attribute from being rewritten. It binds an attribute to the class (without `static` attributes are bound to objects). Maybe you meant `final`?

EDIT: corrected a typo.

Comment: so short answer. no way to do it.

Comment: _"Objects on the other hand are always passed as reference"_ no, they aren't. Object _references_ are passed by value, meaning you get a copy of the reference. You _can_ however, use that reference to make changes to the object it points to, as long as it's not immutable (like a String). If you tried to reassign the passed parameter reference to another object, it would not update the original reference.